# 7zip cannot open output file on some files (PHP, Command Line)

Tags: php, command-line, zip, 7zip, extract

I tried to extract the contents of a zip file in a script I am running with 7zip

```
<?
    $test_zip = $file_directory;
    $cmd = "FOR /R \"$test_zip\" %I IN (*.zip) DO (7z x \"%I\" -aou -o\"%~dpI\" && del \"%~fI\")";
    exec($cmd, $out, $ret);
```

(hundreds and hundreds of files of different types) and it failed. I've used 7zip successfully for other similar zip files so I figured I would try it again and it still failed.

So I tried it again via Command Prompt so I could check the Exit Codes. The results were that it failed, returned a 0 (No Error) for Exit Codes, and I also saw that for ***some*** of the files I received this error: "can not open output file {file name here}". It seemed to be a variety of file types that had this problem and yet the majority of the files in the zip were extracted fine.

If ***all*** the files had this problem I would just figure it was a permissions issue, but I do not know what could make only ***some*** of the files have this problem. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: whats this got to do with php or programming?

Comment: what is? there is no code in the question.

Comment: are the output names valid on the particular OS?

Comment: Long shot, but you do have enough hard disk space, do you?

Comment: @Dagon - I believe so. The file names come from a standard setting, so there is almost no difference between the ones that pass and the ones that fail except a different number, as in "AV39921" and "AV39922", in the file name.

Comment: @Danny_ds - I'm would think so, but I haven't checked that. Are you saying that if the file is big enough it will break the extraction? So why would it print a "can not open output file" error?

Comment: @mario - If 7-Zip needs to create the output file with a size of the uncompressed data, and there is no room left on disk, it will fail on that. That could explain why some files go through while others don't.

Comment: @Danny_ds - But if that's the case shouldn't 7zip be returning an exit code of "8 Not enough memory for operation"? Right now I'm getting a "0 No error" , could that be because it does eventually finish executing?

Comment: Not sure (and as I said, it's a long shot - but it doesn't take long to have a look at the free hard disk space).